# Store android preference in clean way

Tags: android, preferences

How to store android preference in clean way.
I often end up store user preferences in an Singleton class which wrap SharedPreferences but it make painful to maintain when preferences is added.

Comment: what is your definition of "clean way" ?

Comment: Like clean code. It easy to add new preference, easy to use, easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I end up with develope this tiny framework for store preference in android.
https://github.com/CaoManhDat/android-clean-preferences